# Trouble parsing facebook graph api json in python

Tags: python, json, facebook-graph-api

I am having a problem parsing the JSON results from a facebook graph api query (2.5) in python.

I'm trying to get the comments on a status message.

Here's the direct url:
where "specific_post_id" is the id of a status post of a page.
where "access_token" is the app_id and secret_key from facebook.

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/specific_post_id/comments?order=chronological&limit=1&summary=true&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX

The graph explorer is useful as well to see the actual JSON
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

```
def getFacebookPageCommentData(post_id, access_token, num_comments):
    # construct the URL string
    base = "https://graph.facebook.com"
    node = "/" + post_id + "/comments/" 
    parameters = "?fields=id,message,created_time,like_count,parent&limit=%s&access_token=%s" % (num_comments, access_token) # changed
url = base + node + parameters

    # retrieve data
    data = json.loads(request_until_succeed(url))
    return data

test_comment = getFacebookPageCommentData(post_id, access_token, 1)["data"][0]
print test_comment
[{u'created_time': u'2016-02-23T22:37:34+0000',u'id': u'XXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXXXX',u'like_count': 2,u'message': u'"Your" ? Government'}]
```

I expected to get some nested JSON back with a "from" field that contains additional data. However, I don't get that back. I'm sure there is some small error, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: So in your test_comment you take `["data"][0]`, the from data isn't in the rest of the .JSON is it?

Comment: no, it's int the "data" field, but nested.

Comment: OK, so you are expecting that result, but you aren't getting it?

Comment: Yes I'm expecting to have access to the "from" field, but I don't

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104435/discussion-between-12programmerwannabe-and-jcollerton).

Comment: Can you accept that if it works by the way?

Comment: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

and paste your code, and format this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the .JSON returned is pretty confusing and has a lot of nested levels.

If you replace the construction of the URL inside your function:

```
base = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/" 
parameters = "/comments/?access_token=%s" % access_token 
url = base + post_id + parameters
```

Then in the .JSON string returned there are two `data` entries:

```
getFacebookPageCommentData(post_id, access_token, 1)["data"]
getFacebookPageCommentData(post_id, access_token, 1)["comments"]["data"]
```

The second of these contains the `from` information. To then access the `from` data we then do

```
getFacebookPageCommentData(post_id, access_token, 1)["comments"]["data"][0]["from"]
```